# Socks proxy does not work well with remote debugging in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, jvm

My spring-boot application is using socks proxy to access remote servers' resources.

When I launch my application as follows, it works well and my application can access remote resources.

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080
```

But, when I add remote debugging option to this command, socks proxy seems not to work properly and the application can not access remote resources.

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1080 -Drun.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Please tell me the reason why it does not work as expected and tell me any solutions if there are. Thanks in advance.